# Hartshorne II, Prop $5.12$ (c), assumption on $T$ not necessary

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $\varphi\colon S\to T$ be a morphism of graded rings. Let $M$ be a graded $S$-module and let $f\colon U \to \operatorname{Proj}(S)$ denote the induced morphism of schemes, where $U=\{P\in \operatorname{Proj}(T) : \varphi(S_+)\not\subset P\}$.

We have a canonical morphism
$$
\Psi\colon f^\ast(\widetilde{M})\to (M\otimes_S T)^{\sim}\vert_{U}.
$$
Hartshorne writes that, under the assumption that $T$ is generated by $T_1$ as a $T_0$-algebra and $S$ is generated by $S_1$ as a $S_0$-algebra, this map is an isomorphism. However, my proof does not use the assumption on $T$, so I would be glad if someone could check my argument, or at least confirm that the assumption on $T$ is indeed redundant.

Here is the $\textbf{Proof}$: The assumption on $S$ implies that $U=\bigcup_{f\in S_1} D_+(\varphi(f))$. Hence it is enough to check that $\Psi$ restricted to $D_+(\varphi(f))$ is an isomorphism for $f\in S_1$. Now, the morphism
$$
D_+(\varphi(f))\subset U\to \operatorname{Proj}(S)
$$
may be written as
$$
D_+(\varphi(f))\to D_+(f)\subset \operatorname{Proj}(S)
$$
and from the affine case we deduce that $f^\ast(\widetilde{M})|_{D_+(\varphi(f))} = (M_{(f)}\otimes_{S_{(f)}} T_{(\varphi(f))})^{\sim}$.

The canonical isomorphism $(M\otimes_S T)_{\varphi(f)}\cong M_f\otimes_{S_f} T_{\varphi(f)}$ is an isomorphism of graded $T_{\varphi(f)}$-modules and thus restricts to an isomorphism on degree zero. But since $f\in S_1$, we find that the degree zero part of $M_f\otimes_{S_f} T_{\varphi(f)}$ is precisely $M_{(f)}\otimes_{S_{(f)} }T_{(\varphi(f))}$.
Consequently,
$$
f^\ast(\widetilde{M})|_{D_+(\varphi(f))}=(M_{(f)}\otimes_{S_{(f)}} T_{(\varphi(f))})^{\sim} \cong (M\otimes_S T)^{\sim}\vert_{D_+(\varphi(f))}
$$
and one checks that this is equal to the restriction of $\Psi$.

$\textbf{Edit}$ Explanation for why $U=\bigcup_{f\in S_1} D_+(\varphi(f))$: In general, $U=\bigcup_{f\in S_+ \text{ homogeneous}} D_+(\varphi(f))$. Now given $f\in S_d$ homogeneous of degree $d$, there exists a homogeneous polynomial $P(X_1,\ldots,X_r)$ of degree $d$ with coefficients in $S_0$ and elements $x_1,\ldots,x_r\in S_1$ such that $P(x_1,\ldots,x_r)=f$ (using that $S$ is generated by $S_1$ as a $S_0$-algebra). Thus, $\varphi(P)(\varphi(x_1),\ldots,\varphi(x_r))=\varphi(f)$ and therefore $D_+(\varphi(f))\subset D_+(\varphi(x_1))\cup \ldots \cup D_+(\varphi(x_r))$.

Comment: Hou do you get that expression for $U$? If $T$ is not generated by $T_1$ as $T_0$-algebra, then you will also have $D_{+}(\varphi (f))$ for some $f\in S_n, n \geq 2$.

Comment: @Krish I added an explanation for why I think it is true.

Comment: I don't see any problem here. $S$ is generated by $S_1$ as $S_0$-algebra is sufficient to conclude. (Note that the map $\Psi$ exists without any assumption on $S$ and $T$ in terms of generators.)